# How to change wordpress location

Tags: wordpress

I have moved my Wordpress site, but now when I try to log in to dashboard, it sends me to the old site's domain.
I have tried to search in `wp-config.php`, but without success

Where can I change Wordpress's domain name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following to your wp-config.php file.

```
define( 'WP_HOME', 'http://yourdomain.com' );
define( 'WP_SITEURL', 'http://yourdomain.com' );
```

Then login to wp-admin. Go to Settings -> Permalinks and hit save.